# Dependent dropdowns in Magento 2 Frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, ajax, jquery, select

How can I create a pair of dropdowns such that when one is selected, the options for the other one are updated?

PHTML

```
<?php
$stateList = $block->getStates();
?>

    <div>
        <h3 class="text-uppercase margin-bottom15"><?php echo __('Pedir una Cita') ?></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        <div>
            <form id="search_cita">
                <div class="form-group states required">
                    <select id="state" name="state">
                        <option value="">Estado</option>
                        <?php foreach($stateList as $index): ?>
                        <?php  echo '<option value="'.$index['state'].'">'.$index['state'].'</option>'; ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group cities required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <select name="city" id="city" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
                            <!--option value="">Ciudad</option-->    
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo __('Buscar un taller') ?></button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function(){
                jQuery(document).on('change','#state',function() {
                    var param = 'frame='+jQuery('#state option:selected').attr('value');
                    var url = "<?php echo $block->getStateAction(); ?>";
                    //alert(param);
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        showLoader: true,
                        url: url,
                        data: param,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        jQuery('#city').empty();
                        jQuery('#city').append(data);
                    });

                });
        });
    </script>
```

BLOCK

```
<?php
namespace Morwi\Citas\Block;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    protected $_isScopePrivate;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Directory\Block\Data $directoryBlock,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->directoryBlock = $directoryBlock;
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    public function getStateAction() {
        return $this->getUrl('citas/index/display', ['_secure' => true]);

    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
<?php
namespace Morwi\Citas\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;


class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ){          
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {
        //*
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();

        $html='<option selected="selected" value="">Ciudad</option>';

        $stateName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('frame');

        if($stateName!='') {

            $tblSL = $resource->getTableName('store_locator');

            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT city from " . $tblSL . " WHERE state LIKE '%". $stateName ."%'";
            $city = $connection->fetchAll($sql);  

            foreach($city as $index){
                $hmtl= '<option value="'.$index['city'].'">'.$index['city'].'</option>'; 
            }
        }

        return $result->setData(['success'=>true,'value'=>$html]);
        //*/
       }

}

?>
```

But this returns to me

[image]

in success I don't paint the html

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change following line:

```
foreach($city as $index){
   $hmtl .= '<option value="'.$index['city'].'">'.$index['city'].'</option>'; 
}
```

Comment: I made the change, but it still shows the same

Comment: $stateName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('frame'); -> this line too